# Get day number from a specific date

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I can get day no via current date like this, it's give me current result

```js
const dateObject = new Date()
console.log(dateObject.getDay())
```

But When I try to day no of a specific date, I'm not getting actual answer

```js
const dateObject = new Date(2018, 8, 5)
console.log(dateObject.getDay())
```

> I expect 0 , as it's sunday of the week, but I got 3.

What is my fault or misunderstanding here?
Thanks

Comment: Why would it be Sunday? The date you give is in _september_ because the type of Date constructor you used [expected months that start at 0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (there are lots of gotcha's when using Date. So you typically don't use Date directly for calendar "maths"). If you wanted August 5th, 2018, use `Date("2018-08-05")` or `Date(2018,7,5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong with month index. Month mormally start with 0 index.

```
January = 0
February = 1
March = 2
April = 3
...
...
...
...
```

So August month's index number is 7.

You answer will be like this:

```js
const dateObject = new Date(2018, 7, 5)
console.log(dateObject.getDay())
```

Comment: Thanks for this clearance :)

Answer (score 4):

The `monthIndex` parameter in the Date constructor zero-based, so 8 is *September*, not August.  `getDay` then correctly tells you that the fifth of September is a Wednesday.

See MDN for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

There are enough bizarre oddities with JS dates that I just use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) whenever I'm dealing with date/time values.

Answer (score 1):

In `new Date(2018, 8, 5)`, month starts from `0` and not `1`. Hence in your case it is not `August` but `September`.